# transfer several parameters from a form into SQL query

Tags: mysql

i am working on a table that includes a filter function.
For the filter i use a form where i enter the parameters.
Those are added to a string which is my SQL query.
So far it works fine.

There is oine input field where multiple parameters canbe added.
The plan is to seperate them with ; .
For example 520;521;522

My plan was to use str_replace to convert this in to sql Code.

For example

```
$str = str_replace(";", "" OR ", "520;521;522");
```

Results in to:

```
SELECT * FROM MaschinenVorgangslisteMitHV WHERE (VorgangNr LIKE '%520%' or '%522%' or '%523%')
```

But some how this code does not show the expected results.
I only get results for '%520%'

How do i need to adjust this query in order to have the sql query working?

```
$str = str_replace(";", "" OR ", "520;521;522");
```

Results in to:

```
SELECT * FROM MaschinenVorgangslisteMitHV WHERE (VorgangNr LIKE '%520%' or '%522%' or '%523%')
```

In another input field i search for names.
Here the query looks like this...
SELECT * FROM MaschinenVorgangslisteMitHV WHERE (Bearbeiter LIKE '%Heine%' OR Bearbeiter LIKE '%Wolf%' OR Bearbeiter LIKE '%Maiwald%')
This works fine!

Comment: `WHERE (VorgangNr LIKE '%520%' OR VorgangNr LIKE '%522%' OR VorgangNr LIKE '%523%')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple like should be written as,

```
SELECT *  
FROM MaschinenVorgangslisteMitHV  
WHERE VorgangNr REGEXP '520|522|523';
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add `VorgangNr LIKE` after every OR.